# Sum array values based on mapping

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to sum values in an array based on a mapping in a different array.

My mapping looks like this:

```
Sheet "Mapping"
A   B
101 Revenue 
102 Revenue 
103 Cost 
104 Cost 
105 Revenue 
106 Cost
```

My data looks like this:

```
Sheet "Data"
A   B
101 20
102 10
103 -5
104 1
105 -5
106 -6
```

I now want to add all accounts in the data that I have mapped to revenue or cost, i.e.:

```
Revenue = 25
Cost = -10
```

Preferrably with an elegant solution using sumproduct.

I have trouble comparing against a whole array, because I am mostly used to using (--(Array = Value)).

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: show us what columns/sheets your data is in, this will be a simple use of `SUMIF`

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: Why is revenue 25?

Comment: do you have exactly the same items in the same order in both range, or is that something you need to take care?

Comment: @Andreas: 20 + 10 + (-5)

Comment: The data comes in many forms, not always the same order or including all accounts.

Comment: "not always the same order or including all accounts" - that more or less excludes "elegant" solutions, you'll need to use a helper column first to match data, then summarise it (in a pivot table or with SUMIF).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a vlookup and a pivot table.

On mapping sheet C1: (or C2 if you have headers)

```
=Vlookup(A1, 'data-table', 2, FALSE)
```

Where 'data-table' is either a named range of the data sheet range or the data sheet range.

This should move the numbers from data -> mapping table.

Now Insert -> Pivot table and add it to a new sheet.
Set "column B" as rows, and "column C" as values.

Comment: Thank you, this would work. But I would prefer a solution that i) works without pivot tables and ii) (more importantly) keeps the mapping sheet separate and doesn't clutter it with data.

Comment: Can the datasheet have an extra column then?

Comment: Yes, if that helps